# How to resize a table in Pages for Mac?

Tags: macos, pages

How do I resize a table in Pages to fit page?

I am using an iMac with 10.9.5

Answer (score 2):

First select the table by clicking on the table-select circle in the upper left.

Once selected you can grab the right edge of the table at the center select point to adjust the width left and right.

See screenshot.

[image: pages table screenshot]